# Excel duration graphing in minutes and seconds only

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to graph time duration data in Excel using only minutes and seconds but some of my data is over 60 minutes, i.e. 71 minutes and 32 seconds, but Excel formats this data point to 1 hour 11 minutes and 32 seconds. I want to keep it in the format of 71 minutes and 32 seconds. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your Number Formatting to `[mm]:ss;@`?  (Or to `[m]" minutes and "s" seconds";@` if you want the full text blurb)